# How to match specific url with JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match this partial url using RegExp:

```
/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.transmoto.com.au%2Fpublish%2Fnews%2F14614708%2FBopping%2C-Styke-and-Waters-to-lead-Team-Australia-at-MXoN&h=5AQEDldxs&s=1
```

Ideally I need to match the 'u' value and convert it to a proper url (i.e replace %3A with : and %2F with /), but I'd be happy just matching the entire expression.

I've tried a number of RegExp combinations but haven't had any success.

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
var match = url.match(/u=([^&]+)/);

/* Alerts http%3A%2F%2Fwww.transmoto.com.au%2Fpublish%2Fnews%2F14614708
   %2FBopping%2C-Styke-and-Waters-to-lead-Team-Australia-at-MXoN */
alert(match[1]);

/* Alerts http://www.transmoto.com.au/publish/news/14614708/Bopping,-Styke
  -and-Waters-to-lead-Team-Australia-at-MXoN */
alert(decodeURIComponent(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = '/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.transmoto.com.au%2Fpublish%2Fnews%2F14614708%2FBopping%2C-Styke-and-Waters-to-lead-Team-Australia-at-MXoN&h=5AQEDldxs&s=1';
var re = url.match(/\?(?:|.*?&)u=([^&]+)/);
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWDpf/1/).